# Display settings reset to default on login

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg, display, display-resolution

So the basic problem is that when I log in to my computer, after about a second, both screens briefly go black and when they come back on, one monitor is disabled in settings and the other goes to its default/recommended resolution and refresh rate regardless of what I had it set to. It's an Ubuntu 20.04 machine with an NVIDIA RTX 2070s graphics card. The two monitors are a 32" Dell curved monitor and a 22' hp Pavilion. I've tried with a variety of combinations of monitors and cables, and the disabling issue has consistently only happened on the Dell monitor, but the resetting to defaults happened with all of them.

I only noticed the issue when I got this new monitor and started using it. Combined with the fact that it is setting the other monitors to their built-in defaults, my assumption is that for some reason the Dell monitor's default state was disabled (which, granted, doesn't make a ton of sense, but it was a place to start). Based on that information I started with the NVIDIA X Server Settings app that's included with the graphics card to manage that stuff. I ended up having to go in and give it administrative permissions to change its xorg file, and got the default settings correct. After that, the settings that appear initially on login before the screen resets changed to the ones I have saved in X Server Settings, but unfortunately the reset is still occurring.

NVIDIA customer support sent me to a Linux user forum which is what got me that far. We also looked through the log files, but the only thing on there was that the non-Dell monitor (actually an old Vizio smart TV that I had been using as a monitor prior to the current HP mentioned above) was reconnecting  a lot. I changed out that monitor and cable, the log is clean, but the issue still persists.

I also talked to Dell support and they sent me a new monitor in case the old one was creating the issue, but the replacement still isn't working.

I'm fairly certain what's happening is that some other program is resetting everything after NVIDIA does its thing, but I'm not sure what it would be. I haven't installed any other 3rd party graphics managers or anything like that. If anyone knows what could be interfering, that I'll take any suggestions. Alternatively if someone knows how I can do something cheesy like have X Server Settings reapply again 5 seconds after login, that could work. Thanks in advance